# Pagination not working due to htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

i have a rule in my .htaccess as shown below

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ portfolio.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ portfolio.php?id=$1
```

which make every url

```
example.com/portfolio.php?id=50
```

into

```
example.com/portfolio/50/
```

but I've Pagination on this page that isn't working as whenever i try to visit example.com/portfolio/50?page=2 it keeps on showing me the same page 
example.com/portfolio/50.

how could i add page parameter in htaccess rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[QSA]` to the end of those two lines.

"Query String Append" will add the existing query string to the new one your htaccess rule is creating.